# Why did the PostConstruct execute twice in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

I'm using Spring to develop a web application. I just used the mechanism `@PostConstruct` and `@Bean` to invoke a function while starting up.

```
public class MyCache<T> {
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("inittttttttttt");
        // something
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public MyCache<MyData> myCache() {
        return new MyCache<MyData>();
    }
}

public class TextFilter {
    private AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
    private MyCache<MyData> cache;

    public TextFilter() {
        this.context.scan("com.sensitive_words.utils");
        this.context.refresh();
        this.cache = this.context.getBean(MyCache.class);
    }

    public String filter(String originalText) {
        return this.cache.get().filter(originalText);
    }
}
```

As you see, I created a Bean and use the Bean in the class `TextFilter`.

However, I found that the function `init()` is executed twice. Here is the log:

```
2022-10-30 13:53:38.837  INFO 106994 --- [           main] y.c.s.SensitiveWordsApplication          : Starting SensitiveWordsApplication using Java 11.0.16 on yves-Inspiron-5488 with PID 106994 (/home/yves/java_ws/sensitive_words/target/classes started by yves in /home/yves/java_ws/sensitive_words)
2022-10-30 13:53:38.839  INFO 106994 --- [           main] y.c.s.SensitiveWordsApplication          : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-10-30 13:53:39.545  INFO 106994 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8090 (http)
2022-10-30 13:53:39.559  INFO 106994 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-10-30 13:53:39.560  INFO 106994 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.68]
2022-10-30 13:53:39.654  INFO 106994 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-10-30 13:53:39.654  INFO 106994 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 763 ms
inittttttttttt
2022-10-30 13:53:39.769  INFO 106994 --- [           main] s.a.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : No TaskScheduler/ScheduledExecutorService bean found for scheduled processing
inittttttttttt
2022-10-30 13:53:40.080  INFO 106994 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8090 (http) with context path ''
2022-10-30 13:53:40.096  INFO 106994 --- [           main] y.c.s.SensitiveWordsApplication          : Started SensitiveWordsApplication in 1.64 seconds (JVM running for 2.341)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You could create an excepetion in `init` and log the stack trace to help you see why -- or simply put a breakpoint there

Comment: Related: *[Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)*. [Stack Overflow is ***not*** a forum](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/36818/would-you-recommend-stackexchange-sites-vs-other-types-of-forum/36828#36828); it is a Q&A site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see you are setting up two different application contexts of Spring:

1. `SensitiveWordsApplication` does it for you
2. `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context` you created manually in code.

This seems to be the reason. A singleton bean is created one per container by default.

Comment: Ohh, you may be right. I don't know how to get the Bean and google told me I could use `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`...

Comment: you can autowire beans in your class https://www.baeldung.com/spring-autowire